# How to build chain of segments in scope of pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a huge pyspark dataframe with segments and their subsegments, like this:

```
SegmentId  SubSegmentStart SubSegmentEnd
   1         a1               a2
   1         a2               a3
   2         b1               b2
   3         c1               c2
   3         c3               c4
   3         c2               c3
```

I need to group records by SegmentId and add new column *index* to build chain of subsegments using start and end points. I need to do it for each Segment.
So I need to get the following  dataframe:

```
SegmentId  SubSegmentStart SubSegmentEnd  Index
       1         a1               a2        0
       1         a2               a3        1
       2         b1               b2        0
       3         c1               c2        0
       3         c3               c4        2
       3         c2               c3        1
```

How can I do it by PySpark?